# How to make a Table with room library in android studio using Java?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-room

I wanna try to make a table to hold 2 columns with Room Library in android studio with Java (not in Kotlin) .

The problem here, is that my data is something like this :

| Year | Dowry |
| --- | --- |
| 1317 | 0.004 |
| 1318 | 0.004 |
| 1319 | 0.004 |
| 1320 | 0.008 |
| 1400 | 0.255 |

So for this i have made a Class named Data and i valued it like this :

```
    @Entity(tableName = "tbl_data")
public class Data {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private int year;
    private int dowry;
 
    public Data(int year, int dowry) {
        this.year = year;
        this.dowry = dowry;
    }


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getDowry() {
        return dowry;
    }

    public void setDowry(int dowry) {
        this.dowry = dowry;
    }
}
```

and then i made a Database like this :

```
@Database(version = 1 , exportSchema = false , entities = {Data.class} )
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase   {
        private static AppDatabase appDatabase;


    public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
            appDatabase= Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class,
                    "db_app")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        return appDatabase;
    }

    public abstract DataDao getDataDao();

}
```

How to add does data into my data.class AKA "tbl_data" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DataDao interface (or abstract class) that is annotated with @Dao you could have.

```
@Insert
long insert(Data data);
```

You can then insert individual rows e.g.

```
    db = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(this);
    dao = db.getDataDao();
    dao.insert(new Data(1317,0004));
    dao.insert(new Data(1318,0004));
    dao.insert(new Data(1319,0004));
```

The result being (when first run):-

[image]

- Database viewed using Android Studio's [App Inspection](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database)

**However**

using `int` for the dowry doesn't cater for decimal numbers and hence the use of 0004 (which equates to 4).

As such you may wish to change `private int dowry;` to `private double dowry;` *along with changing the code for the respective getters and setters*.

**Multiple/Mass Inserts**

If you added (to DataDao) :-

```
@Insert
long[] insert(Data ... data);
```

Then you could do mass/multiple inserts such as :-

```
dao.insert(new Data(1317,0004), new Data(1318,0004),new Data(1319,0004));
```

The long or long[] is the **id** of the inserted row or rows (or -1 if the row was not inserted).

The following is an example of what could be done with mass inserts, *including interrogating the results*:-

```
    Data[] anotherArrayOfDatas = new Data[100];
    for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        anotherArrayOfDatas[i] = new Data(1300 + i,0.004 + i);
    }
    long[] insertedIdList = dao.insert(anotherArrayOfDatas);
    long insertedOk =0;
    long notinserted = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < insertedIdList.length; i++) {
        if (insertedIdList[i] < 0) {
            notinserted++;
        } else {
            insertedOk++;
        }
    }
    Log.d("INSERTED","Number of inserts was " + insertedOk + ". Number not inserted was " + notinserted);
```

After running the above, the Log includes :-

```
D/INSERTED: Number of inserts was 100. Number not inserted was 0
```

With data in the database looking like :-

[image]

As for handling the string *{1317 | 0.004, 1318 | 0.004, 1319 | 0.004, 1320 | 0.008, ... 1400 | 0.255 }* for input.

Then (assuming that **...** is *and so on*) and thus removed then you need to:-

1. strip off the leading and trailing curly brackets.
2. split the remaining string into an array at each `,`
3. for each array split at the | removing the spaces and then
4. create a Data object from the 2 parts
5. the result should be an Array of Data's that can then be inserted.

As an example :-

First yes another dao has been added to mass insert using an ArrayList as per :-

```
@Insert
long[] insert(ArrayList<Data> dataArrayList);
```

The the following code was added :-

```
    String datain = "{1317 | 0.004, 1318 | 0.004, 1319 | 0.004, 1320 | 0.008,1400 | 0.255 }";
    ArrayList<Data> newDatas = new ArrayList<>();
    String x = datain.substring(1,datain.length() - 1);
    String[] split1 = x.split(",");
    for (String s: split1) {
        s = s.replace(" | ","~");
        String[] parts = s.split("~");
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            try {
                newDatas.add(new Data(Integer.parseInt(parts[0].trim()), Double.parseDouble(parts[1].trim())));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
    dao.insert(newDatas);
```

With the database now including :-

[image]

Comment: thank you so much Mr mike , i have tried all the codes and every single one of them worked for me.